# how to capture if the element style display = "none"

Tags: javascript

A few seconds after loading the page the style of the $('#connecting') is change into display:none.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         agarddack4
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        http*://agar.ddack.oa.gg/
// ==/UserScript==
var s = $('#connecting').css('display')
if (s == "none"){
   console.log("1")
}
```

I tried this to do something if the style of the element change into display:none but it didn't worked.

Comment: I can't test it, the site doesn't seem to load for me

Comment: http://agar.ddack.oa.gg/   site does load to me.

Comment: I can't connect to it either from Canada or the US, it times out on my end

Comment: you can use vpn and connect korea or japan where I connected.

Comment: or would you please let me know without checking the code.

Comment: Instead of directly checking the `display` CSS, you could try using jQuery's visible/hidden selectors, e.g. `$('#connecting').is(':hidden')` Are you trying to wait for the element to disappear? Because if that's the case you will probably need to check in a loop/timeout until it occurs, running it once on load will likely never trigger.

Comment: @DBS  yes I'm trying to wait for the element to disappear. So how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple way to wait for the element to disappear inside a user-script:

Basically, we have a recursive function that will check for the element each second, and repeat until it is finally hidden.

```js
// Relevant code
function check() {
  if ($('#connecting').is(':hidden')) {
    console.log("Hidden!")
  } else {
    console.log("Still visible, trying again in 1 second")
    setTimeout(check, 1000)
  }
}
check()

// This is just for the sake of a functional example
setTimeout(function() {
  $('#connecting').css({
    'display': 'none'
  })
}, 6000)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='connecting'>Connecting...</div>
```